# Why is my logout script not logging out

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a registration and login system working perfectly using PHP and MySQL. My logout isn't working. I have my logout button linked to this script, when I click it the page refreshes but i'm still logged in. Any suggestions

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION['Name'])) {
 header("Location: ../index.php");
 } else if(isset($_SESSION['Name'])!="") {
 header("Location: Home.php");
 }

 if (isset($_GET['Name'])) {
 unset($_SESSION['Name']);
 session_unset();
 session_destroy();
 header("Location: ../index.php");
 exit;
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: Show us the button code. And also how do you know that you are still logged in? We need to see more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to correct the line

```
else if(isset($_SESSION['Name'])!="")
```

to

```
else if(isset($_SESSION['Name']) && $_SESSION['Name'] !="")
```

Otherwise it tries to compare a boolean with a string.